# Почему в docker падает приложение?

Tags: docker

При выполнении команды `docker compose up` база данных разворачивается без проблем, но далее при разворачивании бекэнда выдает ошибку

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "0.0.0.0", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
menu_app |      Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Я так понимаю, что бекэнд не может подключиться к БД через порт 5432. Как мне это исправить?

```
# docker-compose.yaml

version: "3.8"

services:

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:15.1-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
    networks:
      - app_network
    expose:
      - "5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d postgres -U postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5

  app:
    container_name: menu_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    entrypoint: >
      sh -c "
        echo 'Making migrations...' &&
        alembic upgrade head &&
        echo 'Starting project...' &&
        python app/main.py
      "
    networks:
      - app_network
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

networks:
  app_network:
    name: app_network
```

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10-slim

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update -y

EXPOSE 8000

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

CMD ["python", "app/main.py"]
```

```
# main.py

# some code 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1")
```

```
# session.py

# some code

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@db:5432/postgres"

# some code
```

Comment: Зайдите в контейнер `db` и посмотрите IP адрес: `docker exec -it db ip addr`. У меня пишет `inet 172.18.0.2/16`.  Для эксперимента поменяйте `entrypoint` в сервисе `app`: `entrypoint: python -c "import socket; print(socket.gethostbyname('db'));"` и перезапустите compose. У меня в лог выводится `menu_app | 172.18.0.2` - это правильный ответ.

Comment: @PakUula, спасибо за ответ. При изменении `entrypoint` у меня показывает `menu_app  | 172.21.0.2`. Как мне изменить порт на `172.18.0.2`?

Comment: Важно не то, какие цифры в адресе, а то, что адрес `ip addr` в контейнере `db` должен совпадать с адресом `socket.gethostbyname('db')` в контейнере `menu_app`. И, что важно, именно этот адрес должен был увидеть `sqlalchemy`, но вместо этого увидел `connection to server at "0.0.0.0"`. План Б заключается в том, чтобы вместо `db` подставить в строку URL базы данных адрес

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что у меня в `alembic.ini` был прописан хост `0.0.0.0`, вместо `db`:

```
# alembic.ini

# some code 

sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://postgres:postgres@db:5432/postgres

# some code
```

Answer (score 1):

Это не ответ, а продолжение комментария.

Вообще говоря, имя хоста `db` в строке `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL` должно было автоматически распознаться DNS подсистемой докера, и адрес никак не мог быть `0.0.0.0`

Предлагаю план Б. Вместо `db` подставить явный адрес узла:

```py
# some code

addr = socket.gethostbyname('db')
print("DEBUG: db address: ", addr)
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@{addr}:5432/postgres"
```

Comment: У меня возник еще один вопрос: при локальной разработке, при разворачивании в докере и тестировании в докере всегда будут разные порты. Их, получается, каждый раз придется исправлять вручную?